# Compare number column with String in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have couple of columns in Oracle Table.

```
EMP_SEQ_NO  Number(5)
Some_COL    Varchar(20)

EMP_SEQ_NO    Some_COL
10             ABCD
11              11
12             Test
13             Tommy
14              14
15              15
16              Ronny
```

I am trying to do something like

```
Select * from EMP where EMP_SEQ_NO=Some_COL
```

It is throwing Invalid number error.

Please help

Answer (score 5):

Using to_char solves your problem.

```
Select * from EMP where to_char(EMP_SEQ_NO)= to_char(Some_COL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Both of them are of different types. So, you should cast one of them to the type of the other:

```
Select * from EMP 
where CAST(EMP_SEQ_NO as varchar(20)) = Some_COL
```

**OR**

```
Select * from EMP 
where EMP_SEQ_NO = CAST(Some_COL as number(5))
```

Answer (score 0):

to_number will solve this

```
Select * from EMP where EMP_SEQ_NO= to_number(Some_COL, '99999');
```

Comment: Really? `select to_number('ABCD', '99999') from dual;` gives me ORA-01722: invalid number